# Cross reference two lists for a single match in JQuery

Tags: jquery, class

I have two lists in Javascript:

- **newClass** - which is a list of strings (class names)
- **hiddenVals** - which is a list of hidden input elements from `$('input:hidden')` which contain values...

I basically want to be able to go through the list of newClass and check if there is a match in hiddenVals. If so, I will get the value of that hiddenVal.

I have the following working, but I can help but think JQuery has a more concise way of doing it:

```
            var newClass = ui.item[0].parentElement.classList;
            var hiddenVals = $j('input:hidden');
            var newStatusId = -1;

            for (var i = 0; i < hiddenVals.length; i++) {

                var hiddenClass = hiddenVals[i].classList[0];

                for (var x = 0; x < newClass.length; x++) {

                    var test = newClass[x];

                    if (test == hiddenClass) {
                        newStatusId = hiddenVals[i].value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I hope that makes sense and someone can help refactor this appropriately.

Comment: So `.kanban-sortable` is a parent of `2-Development`? Could you show a bit more HTML?

Comment: I have added a code snapshot of the generated HTML in use... I hope this can shine some light on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggested improvements.

```
// use const for constant variables
const classes = ui.item[0].parentElement.classList;
// and let for variables that may change
let newStatusId = -1;

// jQuery's .each() will loop through all elements selected
$('input:hidden').each(element => {
    // for of loop is nicer syntax
    for(let c of classes) {
        // you should use === instead of == to conserve type when comparing
        // but jQuery has .hasClass() which may help
        if($(element).hasClass(c)) {
            newStatusId = $(element).value;
        }
    }
});
```

**Reference**
`const` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const
`let` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let
`for of` loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
`.each()` https://api.jquery.com/each/
`.hasClass()` https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/
`===` [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494)

Comment: Im not sure if I have stated my case very clearly. I am just getting it to work as I want (using some for statements) then will update my question  to see if there is a more efficient way of getting the same result.

Comment: I have updated the question... hopefully this will make more sense now I have trimmed the rubbish out.

Comment: Looks like you got it. I'll update my answer with how I would write this (there are many ways!)

Comment: Looks great and makes good sense... Thanks for that! I am just trying to implement but am not getting any matches on the .hasClass check. Just going to see if I can find out why.